# Using a ComboBox to Change Shapes in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, combobox, powerpoint

I am trying to create a ComboBox for a PowerPoint Slide that would update the shapes on the slides depending on the user's dropdown selection. So far I have the following code, but the selection of the ComboBox item isn't triggering the change of shapes. Does anyone see the flaw in my code and why it is not triggering my shape changes?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
ComboBox1.Clear
    If ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
        With ComboBox1
                .AddItem "Increase", 0
                .AddItem "Decrease", 1
                .AddItem "No Effect", 2
        End With
    End If 
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim l1 As Single
Dim l1m As Single
Dim t1 As Single
Dim t1m As Single

l1 = 3.49 * 72
l1m = 3.32 * 72
t1 = 5.38 * 72
t1m = 5.42 * 72


Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    If ComboBox1.Text = "Increase" Then
        Set shp1 = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeUpArrow, _
        Left:=l1, Top:=t1, Width:=0.35 * 72, Height:=0.28 * 72)

        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Decrease" Then
        Set shp1 = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDownArrow _
        , Left:=l1, Top:=t1, Width:=0.35 * 72, Height:=0.28 * 72)
        shp1.Name = "1"

        Else: ComboBox1.Text = "No Effect"
        Set shp3 = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeMathMinus, _
        Left:=lm1, Top:=tm1, Width:=0.71 * 72, Height:=0.31 * 72)
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You want the code that adds/sizes the shapes to appear in the CHANGE event of the combobox.